# How to add a value in a rollup row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I made a Query to get salaries and in the end a rollup to sum the result but i want to add a text 'Total'.

```
select which as 'Salaries',  IFNULL(SUM(which1),0)  as actual,IFNULL(SUM(which2),0) As estimated
from(select Type_expenses_table as which, sum(Amount_expenses_table) as which1, null as which2
           From bacci.expenses_table
           WHERE Date_expenses_table >= '2017-01-01'
           AND Date_expenses_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
           AND Categories_table = 'salaries'
           group by Type_expenses_table
          union all

select estimated_type as which, null as which1, sum(estimated_amount) as which2 
           From bacci.estimated_expenses_table
           Where estimated_year = '2017'
           AND Categories = 'salaries'
           group by estimated_type


 ) ae
 group by which with rollup;
```

[image]

I want to put Total instead of null

Comment: Add `case` to the outer query

Comment: @zarruq im trying this is always error,
group by which with rollup
case 
when rollup
then 
END as 'Total'

Comment: Try: `SELECT IFNULL(which, 'Total') as 'Salaries', ...`.

Comment: @wchiquito work perfectly Thank you